# Progress Dialog is not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-webview, progressdialog

I want to display progress dialog in my app until it loads the URL and displays it.
But it is not showing the progress dialog.
Please help me.

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("The Book Street");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    progressDialog.show();

    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    WebSettings webSettings = mywb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywb.loadUrl("http://www.thebookstreet.com");

    progressDialog.dismiss();

    mywb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: The problem is you are "showing" the `ProgressDialog` and immediately afterward "dismissing" it. This happens so quickly that you cannot see the dialog appear.

Answer (score 1):

Change your webview client like :

```
mywb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
           }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Progress dialog is deseprecated, I have created a custom class in Kotlin:

```
    class ProgressAlert(private val context: Context) {

    private lateinit var builder: AlertDialog.Builder
    private lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog
    var message = "Loading..."
    var color = Color.BLUE

    fun show() {
        builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setView(layoutInitializer())

        dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }

    fun dismiss() {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    private fun layoutInitializer(): View {
        //Create LinearLayout Dynamically
        val layout = LinearLayout(context)

        //Setup Layout Attributes
        val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        layout.layoutParams = params
        layout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
        layout.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
        layout.setPadding(16, 30, 30, 16)


        // Add elements:

        val progressBar = ProgressBar(context, null, R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge)
        progressBar.isIndeterminate = true
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        progressBar.indeterminateTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)

        //Create a TextView to add to layout
        val textview = TextView(context)
        textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (16).toFloat())
        textview.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0)
        textview.text = message

        layout.addView(progressBar)
        layout.addView(textview)

        return layout
    }

}
```

Using:

```
private val loader = ProgressAlert(this)
```

And set it:

```
loader.run {
            color = Color.BLUE
            message = "Wait a few seconds..."
        }
```

And to show/dismiss it:

```
loader.show()
loader.dismiss()
```